# Why Typescript is not recognizing min.js and .js import?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, react-typescript

Hi I am trying to import some js file of a installed dashboard in a typescript file of React app. But it is not working, Below I have added a screenshot of the imports and error.
Please help:
[image]

Comment: You can just ignore it. It is just a warning, as the type definitions of the library you are using are not available. Or, you can create a declaration file `someName.d.ts` (inside `src` directory) containing, for example, `declare module "adminbsb-materialdesign/js/demo";` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error msg tells you precisely what to do:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/adminbsb-materialdesign
```

In order for typescript to work with external libraries you need to import type definitions (*.d.ts) for them. --save-dev makes the package available in dev time only.

Comment: I did that....but the command gives the error below : 

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fadminbsb-materialdesign - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/adminbsb-materialdesign@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404